# How can I generate a series of numbers based on a cell value in vba and display the results horizontally?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to generate a series of numbers based a on a cell value that can change depending on user input. I need the generated number to increase by +1 equal to the value that the user has input and display the results in the same row but in different cells.

I also need the last number in the series to be saved for the next row of data for the process to start again.

For example if cell A1 = 123456789 (Starting #) and cell B1 = 5 (user input), cells C1 to G1 (results) would equal 123456790, 123456791, 123456792 etc. Then A2 would contain the result of the of the last value used (123456792).

My question is if this is even possible in excel/vba. I have been searching for an answer, however i am not sure exactly what I am looking for. I have only just started learning vba and do not know what it is capable of.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Yes but people are unlikely to do it all for you. You could try Autofill, record a macro and come back if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I am happy to do all of the research myself (not looking for a quick fix) just not sure where to start looking. I will start with the autofill/macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input this

```
=IF(COLUMN()-COLUMN($B1)<=$B1,$A1+COLUMN()-COLUMN($B1),"-")
```

into C1 and copy it to the right.

and A2 `=OFFSET($B1,0,$B1)` and copy down.